# Algoritmo para definir prioridade de ordem de serviço

Tags: javascript, html5

Boa noite. Sou iniciante na programação e estudante de T.I. acabei de criar minha conta aqui no Stackoveflow. 
Tenho noções básicas (BEM básicas) de Python e JavaScript (e HTML e CSS também).

Estou tentando desenvolver um programa simples para um projeto do meu curso, onde temos uma "empresa" de T.I. que precisa de um método de controle de fluxo de atendimento, para definir a prioridade das ordens de serviço.

A ideia é que o programa faça algumas perguntas referente ao atendimento. Cada pergunta recebe um valor caso a resposta seja positiva ou negativa. Ao final do programa, os valores são somados, e se atingem um determinado score, são categorizados como Prioridade 1, Prioridade 2 ou Prioridade 3.

Fiz um modelo usando JavaScript e HTML, porém, não ta funcionando de jeito nenhum.

Peguem leve, sei que muito provavelmente devem ter alguns erros bem esdrúxulos.
Se alguém puder dar uma força, agradeço

```js
var per1 = document.getElementByName('p1');
var per2 = document.getElementByName('p2');
var per3 = document.getElementByName('p3');
var rs = document.getElementById('res');

function calc() {
  if (per1 == 's') {
    var per1 = 1;
  } else if (per1 == n) {
    var per1 = 2;
  } else {
    alert('Por favor, digite um valor válido!');
  }

  if (per2 == s) {
    var per2 = 1;
  } else if (per2 == n) {
    var per2 = 2;
  } else {
    alert('Por favor, digite um valor válido!');
  }

  if (per3 == s) {
    var per3 = 3;
  } else if (per3 == n) {
    var per3 = 1;
  } else {
    alert('Por favor, digite um valor válido!');
  }
  var rs = (per1 + per2 + per2);
  innerHTML.res += ` ${rs}`;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Priority IT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Priority IT - <em>dualreceiver</em></h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div id="d1">
      <img src="dualreceiver.png" alt="Logo dualreceiver">
      <h2>Perguntas:</h2>
      <h3><em>Responda com "s" para SIM ou "n" NÃO:</em></h3>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div id="d2">
    <p><strong>1</strong>. O diagnóstico foi conciso? <input type="text" name="p1"></p>
    <p><strong>2</strong>. Você considera que o problema será resolvido de forma relativamente rápida? <input type="text" name="p2"></p>
    <p><strong>3</strong>. Cliente é PCD, idoso ou necessita atenção especial? <input type="text" name="p3"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick='calc()'>

    <p><div id="res"> Calculando... </div></p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Você tem que pegar os valores dos inputs dentro da função, e não fora. Isso porque ao chamar a função, as variáveis às quais são atribuídas os valores dos inputs estarão sempre vazias no carregamento da página, e a função não irá pegar os valores corretos no momento em que a função for chamada.
2. `document.getElementByName` não existe. Existe `document.getElementsByName` (`Elements` e não `Element`). E como `document.getElementsByName` retorna uma lista de nós, é preciso usar o índice `[0]`, e para pegar o valor do input, acrescentar `.value` no final: `document.getElementsByName('p1')[0].value`.
3. Faltaram as aspas nas strings `s` e `n` dentro dos `if`'s, senão essas letras serão tratadas como variáveis que não existem.
4. Já que as variáveis `per1`, `per2` e `per3` já foram declaradas com `var`, não é necessário utilizar `var` novamente para alterar seus valores.
5. `innerHTML.res` está incorreto. Primeiro vem o elemento e depois o `.innerHTML`, assim: `res.innerHTML`.
6. Coloque um `return` após cada `alert` para impedir que a função chegue até o final em caso de entrar num bloco `else`.
7. Na soma dos valores você repetiu o `per2` no final: `per1 + per2 + per2`, quando o correto seria: `per1 + per2 + per3`
8. No `innerHTML` não precisaria utilizar o operador `+=`. Se você quer substituir o conteúdo da `div#res`, o operador seria apenas o `=`.
9. Colocar uma div dentro de um `<p>` é incorreto no HTML. Você pode utilizar apenas o `<p>`, desta forma: `<p id="res"> Calculando...</p>`.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```js
var rs = document.getElementById('res');

function calc() {
   var per1 = document.getElementsByName('p1')[0].value;
   var per2 = document.getElementsByName('p2')[0].value;
   var per3 = document.getElementsByName('p3')[0].value;
  if (per1 == 's') {
    per1 = 1;
  } else if (per1 == 'n') {
    per1 = 2;
  } else {
    alert('Por favor, digite um valor válido!');
    return;
  }

  if (per2 == 's') {
    per2 = 1;
  } else if (per2 == 'n') {
    per2 = 2;
  } else {
    alert('Por favor, digite um valor válido!');
    return;
  }

  if (per3 == 's') {
    per3 = 3;
  } else if (per3 == 'n') {
    per3 = 1;
  } else {
    alert('Por favor, digite um valor válido!');
    return;
  }
  var rs = (per1 + per2 + per3);
  res.innerHTML = ` ${rs}`;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <h1>Priority IT - <em>dualreceiver</em></h1>
</header>
<section>
   <div id="d1">
      <img src="dualreceiver.png" alt="Logo dualreceiver">
      <h2>Perguntas:</h2>
      <h3><em>Responda com "s" para SIM ou "n" NÃO:</em></h3>
   </div>
</section>
<div id="d2">
   <p><strong>1</strong>. O diagnóstico foi conciso? <input type="text" name="p1"></p>
   <p><strong>2</strong>. Você considera que o problema será resolvido de forma relativamente rápida? <input type="text" name="p2"></p>
   <p><strong>3</strong>. Cliente é PCD, idoso ou necessita atenção especial? <input type="text" name="p3"></p>
   <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick='calc()'>
   <p id="res"> Calculando...</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sei que foram alguns erros meios bobos, vou estudar mais. Obrigado mesmo!